# Can Run code Once in Nested For loop in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I am very new to Swift. Please guide me if I dont know

Is there any function to tell the loop check and run the code once and return

```
 let array = [x1,x2,x3]
 let arr = [a1,a2,a3]
 var Str = String()


for i in 0... array.count-1 {

   for m in 0...arr.count-1 {
      if Str.contains("\(arr[m])"){
        self.Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(arr[m])", with: "\(array[i])", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
}
}
```

if the Str has all a1, a2, a3 in its text.

i = 0, the loop will replace a1, a2, a3 with the x1.

I want the loop find and replace ONE time then stop, so the result I want: 
x1 replaces a1, 
x2 replaces a2,
x3 replaces a3.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To end a loop you use `break`

```
for for i in 0..<array.count {
    if someCondition {
        //do stuff
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace only the first occurrence this is a *swiftier* solution

```
let array = ["x1","x2","x3"]
let arr = ["a1","a2","a3"]
var str = "sdla1fkga2jhsa3ldfkjgh"

for (index, element) in arr.enumerated() {
    if let range = str.range(of: element) {
        str.replaceSubrange(range, with: array[index])
    }
}
```